# Java - Error:cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I am writing a program that calls upon the "invoice" method from a different class in the same folder. I keep getting the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol

strInvoice = invoice();
             ^
symbol: method invoice()
```

Here is how I am calling upon the method in my program:

```
strInvoice= invoice();
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, strInvoice, "*Name*'s Party Store", -1);
```

This is what the method looks like in the class file that is located in the same folder:

```
public String invoice()
{
    String strInfo=""; //string returned containing all the information
    double dBalloonNoDiscount;  //balloon total without discount
    double dCandleNoDiscount;   //candle total without discount
    double dBannerNoDiscount;   //banner total without discount
    double dSubtotal;       //subtotal
    double dTax;            //tax
    double dShippingCost;       //shipping cost
    double dTotal;          //total
    String strShippingType;     //shipping type

    dBalloonNoDiscount = balloons * 2.50;
    dCandleNoDiscount = candles * 6.00;
    dBannerNoDiscount = banners * 2.00;

    dSubtotal = subtotal();
    dTax = tax();
    dShippingCost = shippingCost();
    strShippingType = shippingType();
    dTotal = orderTotal();

    strInfo += "\nQuantity"
        + "\n\nBalloons: " + balloons + " @ $2.50 = " 
            + df.format(dBalloonNoDiscount) + "* Discount Rate: "
            + df.format(discount('B')) + " = " 
            + df.format(subtotal('B'))
        + "\n\nCandles: " + candles + " @ 6.00 = " 
            + df.format(dCandleNoDiscount) + "* Discount Rate: "
            + df.format(discount('C')) + " = " 
            + df.format(subtotal('C'))
        + "\n\nBanners: " + banners + " @ $2.50 = " 
            + df.format(dBannerNoDiscount) + "* Discount Rate: "
            + df.format(discount('N')) + " = " 
            + df.format(subtotal('N'))
        + "\nSubtotal: " + df.format(dSubtotal)
        + "\n  Tax: " + df.format(dTax)
        + "\nShipping: " + df.format(dShippingCost) + " - " 
            + strShippingType
        + "\n Total: " + dTotal;

    return strInfo;
}
```

I hope this is enough info. I just can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: I suggest that you go over some basics of OO and Java, try do couple of simple examples and try this. It will definitely help in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to call a method from a different class, you either need to make that method static or you need to get an instance of the class where it is defined.

In your case you probably need an instance, something like:

```
YourClass instance = new YourClass();
```

and then later:

```
strInvoice = instance.invoice();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
I am writing a program that calls upon the "invoice" method from a different 
class in the same folder.
```

Then you're calling it like:

```
strInvoice= invoice();
```

That cannot work as you will need to call this method as:

```
strInvoice = obj.invoice();
```

Where obj is the instance of the other class.

Alternatively if `invoice()` method is `public static` then you can also call it like:

```
strInvoice = SomeClass.invoice();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are calling the method which is outside the class in which it is called , then you need  a reference before calling a method.

as in your case invoice() method is available in other class and you are calling this method in other class, so you need a reference of class (object) in which invoice() method is available. 
for example :

```
  ClassA object = new ClassA();
  object.invoice();   // assume invoice method is available in ClassA.
```